# Marketing Cloud Responsive Layouts Not Responsive

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html5, css3

Does anyone here ever encountered that the Empty Layouts of Marketing Cloud are not rendering good in some mobile devices (more on iOS Outlook).

[image]

What solution or workaround did you do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You should attach an example and the html code (if you have entered some)

Comment: Hi @JohannesSchapdick, i just used the default blank template of the Marketing Cloud.

Comment: You might find some help here: https://www.howtosfmc.com/building-reusable-email-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a [**Known Issue**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=marketing-cloud-content-builder-out-of-the-box-templates-are-not-responsive-in-the-outlook-app-using-ios-11&Id=a1p3A000000KPJV) on Salesforce side for quite a while, more than [**half a year**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Ca6MQAS). 
It affects exclusively Outlook App on the iOS and is related to the stacked columns.

The only workaround as of moment is custom HTML / CSS, so you should be aware that using pre-built templates or layouts in Content Builder they will not be looking good on the Outlook App on iOS.

I've talked with MC Support about this and learned that since it only affects a very small segment of users (according to Litmus it's around **3%**), it's not very high on the priority list of getting fixed.

It was also recently [talked about](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004lB0mq) in the SMFC Success Group, more or less same response from Salesforce side.

Comment: I am seeing that since MC makes table-based layouts these fail in more than just Outlook clients. Take for instance iPhone 12 on iOS. The issue is their layouts are trying to restyle `<td>` and other table elements with CSS. HTML email is always troublesome, but the fact that these layouts are still using HTML tables is probably most of the issue. Another inconvenience is that the Content Builder tool is made to interact with tables, so you could fix it by making your own DIV layouts, but then lose all the UI tooling.